# Power Spectrum Density of real valued time series data

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, data-analysis, signal-processing

There are real valued time-series data X(t) and corresponding auto-correlation function ACF(t)=$\left<X(0)X(t)\right>$. As written in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density), Power Spectrum Density (PSD) can be calculated using either of X(t) or ACF(t). If one choose to calculate PSD using ACF, I can write the following : $PSD(\omega)=\mathcal{F}\{ACF(t)\}$. However, I get PSD which is complex number with non-infinitesimal imaginary value. From the method which uses $X(t)$ for PSD, I think PSD should be real number ($PSD(\omega)=E\left[|\hat{X}(\omega)|^2\right]$). I have two choices: 1) taking only real part 2) taking norm (using |z|=$\sqrt{zz^*}$). Which one is valid method?

Comment: Use the definition $PSD(\omega)=E\left[|\hat{X}(\omega)|^2\right]$... the fact $PSD(\omega)=\mathcal{F}\{ACF(t)\}$ is less general, as it can be applied only to stationary processes.

Answer (score 1):

The [autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) function is defined as:
$$
r_{a b}\left( i, j \right) = E\left[ a_{i} \ b_{j}^{*} \right] \tag{0}
$$
where $a(b)$ is an arbitrary time series signal and $i(j)$ is the corresponding index, respectively.  The $E\left[ x \ y \right]$ term is the [expectation value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) between $x$ and $y$ and the asterisk indicates the [complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate) of the argument.

The [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of a time series signal $x(t)$ is given by:
$$
\tilde{x}\left( \omega \right) = \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{ 2 \ \pi } } \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ dt \ x\left( t \right) \ e^{-i \ \omega \ t} \tag{1}
$$
where $\omega$ is the angular frequency.  The inverse involves switching $\tilde{x}$ and $x$ and changing the sign of $i$ in the exponent.

Then the [power spectral density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density) or PSD is defined by:
$$
s_{x}\left( \omega \right) = C_{o} \ \lvert \tilde{x}\left( \omega \right) \rvert^{2} \tag{2}
$$
where $C_{o}$ is a constant used for normalization and units, depending on method and/or computer language used (they each have slightly different normalizations for FFTs).

The [Wiener–Khinchin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem) allows you to define the autocorrelation function of $x(t)$ in terms of the PSD or the converse.  That is, the PSD can be defined as:
$$
s_{x}\left( \omega \right) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ dt \ r_{x x}\left( t \right) \ e^{-i \ \omega \ t} \tag{3}
$$

> I have two choices... Which one is valid method?

In principle, they are the same.  If you already have $x(t)$ why bother with the autocorrelation, just take the absolute value squared of the FFT of $x(t)$ (with proper normalization included based upon the specific language used).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. However, you slightly misunderstood my question. I already know that there are two methods to calculate PSD but my question already assumes following PSD calculation from FFT of ACF. The real question is FFT of ACF gives imaginary part which cannot be ignored and there are two ways to make it real number.